# CMake insert in file in a specific line

Tags: html, cmake

Is it possible to inser text from a CMakeLists.txt into a file in a specific line (and move one line down the rest of the lines).

I have read the FILE function documentation http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html but I cannot find anything.

Objective: From CMake, I want to modify a HTML file so that the directory of the index.html is wrote in this HTML file (potentially as a link). I am creating a file to log different things (output files directories). For example:

File before running cmake:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- Insert text here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

File after runing a CMakeLists.txt with something like

```
file((insert in line 6) ${DOC_DIR}/log.txt "<p>Inserted text.</p>")

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- Insert text here -->
       <p>This text is normal.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`configure_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) to fill a template with CMake variables.

Simple example:

**test.html.in**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    @html_string@
    </body>
</html>
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(test)
set(html_string "<p>Inserted text.</p>")
configure_file(test.html.in test.html)
```

Running `cmake` results in a file **test.html** with the following contents to be created:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Inserted text.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking on that but I wanted to know if there were any simpler way. I will try this out, since my CMake config is actually complex and reformulate the question if it does not work :)